# wxPython with data string as message

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, arcgis

How can I use wxPython to take data string which is obtained as part after calculations and display it as a message or report with OK/Cancel options? It would then be upto me to either save or cancel it. Note: I want to use simple app (to avoid arcmap crash) as this report generation is part of a pythonaddin within arcgis 10.1 setup.

Answer (score 3):

You can use wxPython dialogs in a pythonaddin, but only if you get things set up correctly. You have to import wx and create the wx.App in an extension addin which auto-loads and has a startup method. That will allow the wx.App (or PySimpleApp) to be created before the Arcmap event loop starts. Below is part of a working extension that is used in my company which uses wxPython dialogs.

```
import os, sys, time
import shutil

#do exception handler imports now
##mp = os.path.dirname(__file__)
mp = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(mp)

from aiHelpers2 import print2log, ehook
print2log(u'finished standard library imports . . .')

sys.excepthook = ehook
print2log(u'set except hook')

import wx      # always load in ext (extension loads before event loop starts)
import arcpy
import pyodbc  # need to import here for toolbox scripts (loads before loop)

app = wx.App(0)

class LibLoader1(object):
    '''Implementation for wvExten_addin.ext2 (Extension)'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True

    def startup(self):
        '''
        Internally esri-activated addin method, runs when Arcmap starts. 
        Sets up the environment. 
        '''
        soforth, so-on . . .
```

We only use wx.Dialog sub-classes in this app, so we don't need a mainloop. But you can use one, I've tried it.

All that said, I think there is an easier answer to the issue you mentioned.  If you simply want to display results from some processing, then you can write the results to a file (or mmap if you prefer) and use subprocess.Popen to fire off a script that reads the file or mmap and displays the contents in a wx dialog or frame.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I not only want to display results, but select one of the options as a string and use that selection for the next processing in line. I am diving myself further into wxPython to meet my needs. If you have any suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According to ESRI's website, they do not support wxPython integration in 10.1: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/41809-wxPython-hooked-to-arcmap

It sounds like you can get it to sort of work, but it sounds pretty buggy to me. There may be a way to use one of the arcgis Python modules to show a dialog from with ArcGIS. I would look into that and / or ask on their forums.

Comment: They provide following limited options with dialogues:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/The_pythonaddins_module/014p00000021000000/

Tinker comes as default for GUI designing but wxPython can be used if installed separately. The only problem with arcmap.exe is its conflict with the event loop of wxPython. But simple app can be used as an alternate and an example is provided in this video by ESRI:
http://video.esri.com/watch/1229/arcmap-and-python-closing-the-vba-gap

Current pythonaddins only gives the option to display a message instead of strings of info.